# AngularJs - How can I disable the submit button until the current text on my input is updated?

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue try to achieve this result, pretty much what I need is to disable the submit button until the current text in the input field is updated. Please if you can help me with this it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: You can use ng-change="()" on text field

Comment: @Archael Anie Share the code

Comment: @Gangadhar, I am pretty much begginer but I tried ng-disabled. I searched many times and I did not see any hint on how I can do that.  if you can give me any suggestion or hint on how I can do that it would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Archael Anie is this what you are looking  for  http://plnkr.co/edit/7nXi1Bs8z17DvocISmk9?p=preview

Comment: @Archael Anie the requirement is to  enable the button only  after  you  enter  the textbox right  ?

Comment: @anil chean, Thank you for your suggestion I appreciate that. But its not what I am looking for. I have a input field with default value, I want to update that. but I want my submit button to be disabled until I commit a changes in my default texton my input filed.

Comment: @Archael Anie can you  share your code in  plunker ?

Comment: @anilchean check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42572490/3543808)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample of disabling button until you enter some value in input
Using [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) and `$dirty`

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Angular Form";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!form.name.$dirty">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Have a look at angularJS form validations:
  [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)
  [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. check out this image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH638.png). the text inside the text field is a defaukt text. but I want to disbale the submit button until I commit a changes in my defaul text.

Comment: @ArchaelAnie What do you mean by `commit` ?. BTW my example will do the same I guess

Comment: I mean, the button will remain disable until I changes the value inside the text area. (example: i type "a",    the button will enable).

Comment: My example is doing the same. Isn't it?. If not, can you quickly create working demo to replicate the issue you have?

Comment: Yes it close :) It solve my problem by the way. Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gangadhar Jannu

Comment: @ArchaelAnie. I'm glad my answer helped :)